# Expandable text in a Container

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a container to show reviews from users. The container have some properties such as the profile image, rating, etc. At the bottom of the container I want to put the review text, and if it is too long, make a "read more" / "read less" botton and adjust the size of the container. This is the code I am using:

```
Container(
     height: 500.0,
     width: double.infinity,
     child: ReviewListWidget(userProfile: userProfile),
)
```

```
Some constrais...

class ReviewListWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final UserProfile userProfile;

  const ReviewListWidget({
    @required this.userProfile,
  });

  @override
  _ReviewListWidgetState createState() => _ReviewListWidgetState();
}

class _ReviewListWidgetState extends State<ReviewListWidget> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _buildView(context);
  }

  void onTapReadMore(bool _flag) {
    setState(() => _flag = !_flag);
  }

  Widget _buildView(BuildContext context) {
    final Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    String firstHalf;
    String secondHalf;
    bool _flag = true;

    return ListView.builder(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
      controller: ScrollController(),
      itemCount: widget.userProfile.reviews.length,
      itemBuilder: (_, i) {
        final review = widget.userProfile.reviews[i];

        //Logic to make the body review expandable
        if (review.bodyReview.length > 150) {
          firstHalf = review.bodyReview.substring(0, 150);
          secondHalf =
              review.bodyReview.substring(150, review.bodyReview.length);
        } else {
          firstHalf = review.bodyReview;
          secondHalf = "";
        }

        return Container(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Row(...Here Goes the profile picture, etc.),
              SizedBox(height: 12),
              
              secondHalf.isEmpty
                  ? Text(firstHalf)
                  : Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        new Text(_flag
                            ? (firstHalf + "...")
                            : (firstHalf + secondHalf)),
                        new InkWell(
                          child: new Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              new Text(
                                _flag ? "Read more" : "Read less",
                                style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          onTap: () => onTapReadMore(_flag),
                        ),
                       ],
                      ),
                   );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

The problem with this implementation is that when I press the button the value of _flag is not being updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put `_flag` variable into class, otherwise `_buildView` method will create a new variable with `true` value on every build. So, the code should look like this:

```dart
class _ReviewListWidgetState extends State<ReviewListWidget> {
  bool _flag = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _buildView(context);
  }

  void onTapReadMore() {
    setState(() => _flag = !_flag);
  }

  Widget _buildView(BuildContext context) {
    final Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    String firstHalf;
    String secondHalf;

    return ListView.builder(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
      controller: ScrollController(),
      itemCount: widget.userProfile.reviews.length,
      itemBuilder: (_, i) {
        final review = widget.userProfile.reviews[i];

        //Logic to make the body review expandable
        if (review.bodyReview.length > 150) {
          firstHalf = review.bodyReview.substring(0, 150);
          secondHalf =
              review.bodyReview.substring(150, review.bodyReview.length);
        } else {
          firstHalf = review.bodyReview;
          secondHalf = "";
        }

        return Container(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Row(...Here Goes the profile picture, etc.),
              SizedBox(height: 12),
              
              secondHalf.isEmpty
                  ? Text(firstHalf)
                  : Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        new Text(_flag
                            ? (firstHalf + "...")
                            : (firstHalf + secondHalf)),
                        new InkWell(
                          child: new Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              new Text(
                                _flag ? "Read more" : "Read less",
                                style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          onTap: () => onTapReadMore(),
                        ),
                       ],
                      ),
                   );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Putting _flag where you said doesn't fix the problem. It is happening the same, every time I press the button the variable is initialize as true :(

Comment: @Jsancs you also have to remove variable definition from buildView as I did

Comment: Oh that's true, now it works :) Some idea to make the container's height as high as the text? Thank you so much

Comment: @jsancs not really. I think you have to dig down MediaQuery.